# Trying to create a temp table in Microsoft SQL Server but keep getting hit with an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, temp-tables

```
create table #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
(
    continent nvarchar(255),
    location nvarchar(255),
    date datetime,
    Population numeric,
    people_fully_vaccinated numeric, 
    [%_of_pop_vaxxxed] numeric,
    rn int
)

insert into #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
    select 
        cd.continent, cd.location, cd.date, cd.population, 
        vac.people_fully_vaccinated, 
        (cast(vac.people_fully_vaccinated as int) / cd.population) * 100 as [%_of_pop_vaxxxed], 
        rn = row_number() over (partition by cd.Location order by (vac.people_fully_vaccinated / cd.population) * 100 desc, cd.Date) 
    from 
        coviddeaths as cd 
    join 
        covidvaccinations vac on cd.location = vac.location  
                              and cd.date = vac.date
    where 
        cd.continent is not null

select *
from #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
```

Error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

This error is odd; I'm sure it has to do with row number

Comment: provide some sample values and see why it is failing

Comment: when I tried it is working fine for me. may be you are getting some error outside this batch

Comment: i feel like the problem is the row_number function. it just doesnt work for me

Comment: btw, There are multiple problems in your temp table definition.

- Don't use keywords as column names. E.g., `date`
- Don't specify just the datatype. Always specify length. E.g.,  `numeric`

Comment: What is your version of sql server

Comment: What continent name requires 255 characters?

Comment: You should always explicitly list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: I agree - never use an insert statement without listing columns. You're inviting issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

First if that is your temporary table, you should first check if that table exist and drop it.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#PercentofPopulationVaccinated') is not null drop table #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
```

After that table definition should be:

```
create table #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
(
    continent nvarchar(20),
    data_location nvarchar(255),
    data_date datetime,
    total_population float,
    people_fully_vaccinated float, 
    [%_of_pop_vaxxxed] decimal(8,4),
    rn
)
```

and your select:

```
insert into #PercentofPopulationVaccinated (
    continent,
    data_location,
    data_date,
    total_population,
    people_fully_vaccinated, 
    [%_of_pop_vaxxxed],
    rn int
    )
select 
    cd.continent, 
    cd.location, cd.date, cd.population, 
    vac.people_fully_vaccinated, 
    (vac.people_fully_vaccinated / cd.population) * 100 as [%_of_pop_vaxxxed], 
    rn = row_number() over (partition by cd.Location order by 
    (vac.people_fully_vaccinated / cd.population) * 100 desc, cd.Date) 
from 
    coviddeaths as cd 
join 
    covidvaccinations vac on cd.location = vac.location  
                              and cd.date = vac.date
where 
    cd.continent is not null

select *
from #PercentofPopulationVaccinated
```